# preg_split by words including trailing white spaces

Tags: php, whitespace, preg-split

What's the regex to use in preg_split in this example?

Example

```
<?$a='Word  with  white   trailing   spaces.    ';
```

Output

```
Array(
[0] => 'Word  ',
[1] => 'with  ',
[2] => 'white   ',
[3] => 'trailing   ',
[3] => 'spaces.    '
)
```

I've no idea in regex in php. I just need to minimize the code. Maybe someone could help me and explain a little bit about the answered regex

Comment: People are here to help you if you run into a problem with something you have actually tried to accomplish, not to write code on demand.

Comment: @jprofitt It's so tempting to just do these little easy requests for the rep, though.

Comment: (\w+) should match all the words minus the spaces.  Or do you need to keep the spaces intact?

Comment: @Philip I need to keep the spaces sir

Comment: basically you need to grab every word + everything thats not a word, im working on an example for you

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I see the OP wanted an explanation.
Basically () groups a word(s) \w+ and any non word \W+ up until the point it finds an new word @). so ( anything in here ) = $1

```
$str = "Word  with  white   trailing   spaces.    ";


$split = preg_split("/(\w+\W+)/", $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

var_dump($split);
```

Comment: ...or you could do that.  But that's far too simple. :)

Comment: @MarkReed :) any idea why it throws in empty key/paris? hence PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY, taken from your example btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one option:

```
array_map('join', 
  array_chunk(
    preg_split('/(\s+)/', $a, null, 
               PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY),
    2));
```

Taking it by steps.

1. Split by any amount of whitespace - `\s+`
2. But remember the whitespace - that's the parentheses and the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag.

   This gives you an array that looks like this:

   ```
   array('Word', '  ', 'with', '  ', 'white', '   ',
         'trailing', '   ', 'spaces.', '    ')
   ```
3. Pass the result to `array_chunk` with a chunk_size of 2.

   Now we have an array of 2-element arrays:

   ```
   array(array('Word', '  '), array('with', '  '), ... )
   ```
4. Pass that result to `array_map` with a callback of `join` - which joins each pair of strings into one string, and gives us the desired result:

   ```
   array('Word  ', 'with  ', ...);
   ```